# Why doesn't my javascript code work in functions.php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've developed a theme in wordpress and it all works fine except for the javascript. What is the problem?

This is the code in functions.php

```php
function dstrkt_script_enqueue() 
{

    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/customstyle.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/icons.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('demo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/demo.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

    wp_enqueue_script('customjs' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dstrkt.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('borderMenu' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/borderMenu.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('classie' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/classie.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dstrkt_script_enqueue');

function dstrkt_theme_setup() 
{

    add_theme_support('menus');

    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary Header Navigation');
    register_nav_menu('secondary', 'Footer Navigation');

}

add_action('init', 'dstrkt_theme_setup');
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('classie' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/classie.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);` Is it working for you ?

Comment: No unfortunately.This is something that i tried before and nothing changed.

Comment: Do you mean that the js files aren't being loaded?

Comment: First Inspect and check js and css loaded or not if loaded then check file has  permission  or not .

Comment: Sourabh i ve inspected and js and css are loaded(http://test.fluxmusic.net/) how can I see If file has pemission? And what I can do If not?

Comment: You most probably don't have `wp_footer()` in the footer